# Canvas Framework for interactive elastic line?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to create a interactive elastic line for my webpage, when the user  hover the line it will animate like elastic effect or rubber band stretch effect and mouse leave the object will back to the original shape.

Demo Object

[image]

I'm the Newbie in HTML5 Canvas, I hope it done with JavaScript canvas library, but when I searching best canvas library I get many more options, so I'm getting confused to which one select to achieving my goal. [ThreeJs](http://threejs.org/), [fabricJs](http://fabricjs.com/) , [PaperJs](http://paperjs.org/) , etc are the popular canvas libraries.

I would like suggestions of which framework would be the most suitable for my goal.

Thanks and Appreciate your helping mentality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use Inverse Kinematic, or more specifically a [Kinematic Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinematic_chain).

There are many approaches more or less complex. Here is a simple approach which will allow you to drag the end point around and the rest will follow. It's not perfect but will probably do for this purpose.

## (Inverse) Kinematic Chain

The main function is as follows. It assumes that an array with points is defined as well as a `distance` variable:

```
// calculate IK chain (from last to first)
function calc() {

    var angle, i, p1, p2;

    for(i = points.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        p1 = points[i];                                // current point
        p2 = points[i-1];                              // previous point
        angle = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);  // calc angle

        p2.x = p1.x + distance * Math.cos(angle);      // update previous point
        p2.y = p1.y + distance * Math.sin(angle);      // based on a fixed distance
    }
}
```

Notice that the `distance` variable is set to a fixed length which is the key here.

All we need to do now is to detect the mouse dragging the last point in the chain and the rest will follow.

## Chain in action

```js
var c = document.querySelector("canvas"),
 ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    
    // the chain - dragged by the *last* point
 points = [
  {x: 50, y: 50},
  {x: 100, y: 60},
  {x: 90, y: 90},
  {x: 120, y: 110},
  {x: 200, y: 80},
  {x: 250, y: 130}
 ],
 distance = 50,
 isDown = false;

// set canvas size
resize();
window.onresize = resize;

function resize() {
  c.width = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = window.innerHeight;
  calc();
  render()
}

// handle mouse
c.onmousedown = function(e) {
  var pos = getXY(e), 
      p = points[points.length - 1];

  isDown = (pos.x > p.x - 7 && pos.x < p.x + 7 && pos.y > p.y - 7 && pos.y < p.y + 7);
};

window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (!isDown) return;
 
  points[points.length - 1] = getXY(e);    // override last point with mouse position

  // update chain and canvas
  calc();
  render(); 
};

window.onmouseup = function() {isDown = false};

// adjusted mouse position
function getXY(e) {
 var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
 return {
  x: e.clientX - rect.left,
  y: e.clientY - rect.top
 }
}

// IK chain calculations
function calc() {
 
 var angle, i, p1, p2;
 
 for(i = points.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  p1 = points[i];
  p2 = points[i-1];
  angle = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
  
  p2.x = p1.x + distance * Math.cos(angle);
  p2.y = p1.y + distance * Math.sin(angle);
 }
}

// render line and handle
function render() {

 var lp, radius = 7;
 
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
 
 // render current chain
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
 for(var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
 ctx.lineWidth = 3;
 ctx.strokeStyle = "#07f";
 ctx.stroke();
 
 lp = points[points.length - 1];
 
 // draw handle
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(lp.x + radius, lp.y);
 ctx.arc(lp.x, lp.y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
 ctx.lineWidth = 2;
 ctx.strokeStyle = "#900";
 ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

## Going back to the roots

In order for it to bounce back you will need the original coordinates, then interpolate with the corresponding points in the chain.

This would of course happen on the mouse up event. You can use easing functions if you so wish; ease-out would probably be the most suitable in this case.

## Bounce back

This example does not intend to solve the entire problem, neither is it optimized but, you should be able to get the gist of what is needed. Modify as needed.

For this to work:

- The render function now takes an argument so we can feed it any point array
- We need to interpolate between the fixed points (original path) and the IK chain. For this we use a temporary array.
- We animate while t is [0, 1]
- When done, we reset the IK points to the original and recalc/render it.
- I also added min/max for a chain segment to show how you can make the chain more elastic on its own.

```js
var c = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    
    // the fixed point chain
    pointsFixed = [
      {x: 50, y: 50},
      {x: 100, y: 60},
      {x: 90, y: 90},
      {x: 120, y: 110},
      {x: 200, y: 80},
      {x: 250, y: 130}
    ],

    // for the IK chain - dragged by the *last* point
    points = [
      {x: 50, y: 50},
      {x: 100, y: 60},
      {x: 90, y: 90},
      {x: 120, y: 110},
      {x: 200, y: 80},
      {x: 250, y: 130}
 ],
    
    min = 40, max = 70,
    isDown = false,
    
    // for animation
    isPlaying = false,
    t, step = 0.1;       // t = [0, 1]

// set canvas size
resize();
window.onresize = resize;

function resize() {
  c.width = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = window.innerHeight;
  calc();
  render(points)
}

// handle mouse
c.onmousedown = function(e) {
  var pos = getXY(e), 
      p = points[points.length - 1];

  isDown = (pos.x > p.x - 7 && pos.x < p.x + 7 && pos.y > p.y - 7 && pos.y < p.y + 7);
};

window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (!isDown) return;
 
  points[points.length - 1] = getXY(e);    // override last point with mouse position

  // update chain and canvas
  calc();
  render(points); 
};

window.onmouseup = function() {
  if (isDown) {
    isDown = false;
    t = 0;                // reset t for new animation
    isPlaying = true;     // allow looping
    animate();            // start the animation
  }
};

// adjusted mouse position
function getXY(e) {
  var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: e.clientX - rect.left,
    y: e.clientY - rect.top
  }
}

// IK chain calculations
function calc() {
 
  var angle, i, p1, p2, dx, dy, distance;
 
  for(i = points.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    p1 = points[i];
    p2 = points[i-1];
    dx = p2.x - p1.x;
    dy = p2.y - p1.y;
    angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    distance = Math.max(min, Math.min(max, Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)));
  
    p2.x = p1.x + distance * Math.cos(angle);
    p2.y = p1.y + distance * Math.sin(angle);
  }
}

// interpolate and animate
function animate() {
  if (isPlaying) {
    
    // create a temp. array with interpolated points
    for(var i = 0, p, pts = []; i < points.length; i++) {
      pts.push(lerp(points[i], pointsFixed[i], t*t));  // t*t for easing
    }
    
    // increase t in animation
    t += step;
    
    // keep animating?
    if (t <= 1) {
      render(pts);
      requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    }
    else {
      // we're done
      isPlaying = false;
      points = pts;
      calc();
      render(points);
    } 
  }
  
  function lerp(p1, p2, t) {
    return {
      x: p1.x + (p2.x - p1.x) * t,
      y: p1.y + (p2.y - p1.y) * t
    }
  }
}

// render line and handle
function render(points) {

  var lp, radius = 7;
 
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
 
 // render current chain
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
  for(var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#07f";
  ctx.stroke();
 
  lp = points[points.length - 1];
 
  // draw handle
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(lp.x + radius, lp.y);
  ctx.arc(lp.x, lp.y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#900";
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: @Krish. K3N has a good idea with kinematic chain(s) -- upvote. Now it's time for you to take these ideas and implement them with your own designs & code. ;-)

Comment: Thank you both of you @K3N  & markE

Answer (score 1):

**The technique you're looking for is `poly line simplification`.**

Your question borders on being off-topic because it asks for a library recommendation. But there isn't a library that automatically animates your demo path as you describe.

*So I guess there's no harm in saying ...*

You can define and draw your "wiggly" path as a set of connected points (a polyline). Then when your user moves off the path you can use a path simplification algorithm to remove poly-points until the path "straightens out".

The [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://gist.github.com/rhyolight/2846020) is one useful path simplification algorithm.

[Here's an example](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/) of path simplification in action. In the demo, move your mouse rightward to simplify the path and move leftward to show the more complex path (complex==more points on the path).

Comment: Does threeJs is possible?

Comment: No. ThreeJS doesn't have that capability.

Comment: I need something like this http://paperjs.org/examples/chain/, the fluid animation actually want @markE

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :-) That's like the "snake" game.

Comment: Can I get your email ID  for the further assistance @markE

Comment: Time is limited so I can't offer further assistance beyond pointing you in a good direction. I suspect you will have success if you combine (1) the Kinematics that @K3N suggests, (2) the line-path simplification that I suggest, (3) `requestAnimationFrame` & (4) maybe some easing.